# Look for number of duplicates and copy the line in batch

Tags: batch-file, duplicates, findstr

In ***File_1*** I have:

```
Word_1;ger
Word_1;gr
Word_1;greber
Word_1;gaerfsd
Word_2;gerbhge
Word_2;tgbzrfvd
Word_3;gzfdfdc
```

I want to calculate the number of duplicates of each first column of each line then, depending on the number of duplicates(one or different than one), I will copy paste them to two different files.

***File_2*** will contain:

```
Word_3;gzfdfdc
```

***File_3*** will contain:

```
Word_1;ger
Word_1;gr
Word_1;greber
Word_1;gaerfsd
Word_2;gerbhge
Word_2;tgbzrfvd
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    (for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=;" %%a in (File_1) do (
        set current_line=%%a
        if "!current_line!" NEQ "!previous_line!" (
            for /f %%C in ('Find /C %%a ^< File_1) do (
                set Count=%%C
                if "!Count!==1" (
                        findstr %%a File_1 >>File_2
                )
                if not "!Count!==1" (
                        findstr %%a File_1 >>File_3
                )
            )
        )
        set previous_line=!current_line!
    )
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any Help ?

Comment: `%count%` should be `!count!`

Comment: What's the reason @Stephan? It doesn't work either

Comment: Reason id [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082). Thought, you knew, because you are already using delayed expansion correctly with `current_line`. Didn't test your code. Correct the `count` issue and then post any occuring errormessages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed an unneeded variable, corrected an erroneous `if` syntax and added some quotes for "best practice". Seems to do exactly, what you intend:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=;" %%a in (File_1.txt) do (
  if "%%a" NEQ "!previous_line!" (
    for /f %%C in ('Find /C "%%a" ^< File_1.txt') do (
      if "%%C"=="1" (
        findstr "%%a" File_1.txt >>File_2.txt
      ) else (
        findstr "%%a" File_1.txt >>File_3.txt
      )
    )
  )
  set "previous_line=%%a"
))
```

Comment: @Aacini ugh - I was sure, I took it out (therefore "removed an unneeded variable") - done; thanks for spotting.